# Is app distribution possible simultaneously for smartphone and Wear with Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-distribution

I wrote two apps for Android for the department I work at. One Wear and one Mobile App, which are in one project. I registered the app with Firebase and downloaded the Firebase Tester app to the phone. I also used the Android Studio terminal to create and sign APKs and automatically uploaded them to the Firebase system. The mobile app now shows me both apps with the respective version number. I can install the smartphone app from there without any problems. The installation of the Wear app logically fails. I have not found a tester app for the smartwatch. Am I missing something? Does Firebase also distributes to the wear?

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a solution via Firebase, although I am sure there must be a solution. Currently it still works with the app "Wear Installer" from the Playstore. This is cumbersome, but you can download the APK for the Wear app via the gmail email and then transfer and install it using the "Wear Installer" app.